# Why did Magento create an order but not link it to the Sage Pay transaction?

Tags: magento, opayo

We have set a Magento site set up for a customer and it's using the Sage Pay Suite CE module, most orders are going through correctly but we had one come through which has behaved quite strangely. I got the following mage error on a Sage Pay orphaned transaction:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '48-0-1' for key 'PRIMARY'0000 : The Authorisation was Successful.
```

The strange thing is that it has actually created the order but there seems to be a problem with it, it doesn't have any Sage Pay details associated with it. The client also claims to have sent it and marked it as as completed, however it has now gone back to processing and there is no way for me to mark it as complete. The store also didn't receive an email informing them the order had been created, they said that the customer did but this may have been a Sage Pay email confirmation not a Magento one.

This might be something to do with the method of payment as they get many customers using Coutts cards, this transaction was one such customer. Another thing is, if I look at the Sagepaysuite_transaction table in the database, that particular transaction has no order id associated with it, its set to NULL.

Any help you can provide would be greatly appreciated.

Kind Regards Ross

Edit - Bit more info, got some stack trace info from the SagePaySuit

```
2014-12-30 13:28:07.000000 (1419946087.15) ERR: 
exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '48-0-1' for key 'PRIMARY'' in /home/pixie/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228
Stack trace:
#0 /home/pixie/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php(228): PDOStatement->execute(Array)
#1 /home/pixie/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#2 /home/pixie/public_html/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#3 /home/pixie/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#4 /home/pixie/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `ca...', Array)
#5 /home/pixie/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(428): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `ca...', Array)
#6 /home/pixie/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Indexer/Price/Default.php(564): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('INSERT INTO `ca...')
#7 /home/pixie/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Indexer/Price/Default.php(142): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Indexer_Price_Default->_movePriceDataToIndexTable()
#8 /home/pixie/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Indexer/Price.php(315): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Indexer_Price_Default->reindexEntity(Array)
#9 /home/pixie/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/CatalogInventory/Model/Observer.php(749): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Indexer_Price->reindexProductIds(Array)
#10 /home/pixie/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1338): Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Observer->reindexQuoteInventory(Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#11 /home/pixie/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1317): Mage_Core_Model_App->_callObserverMethod(Object(Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Observer), 'reindexQuoteInv...', Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#12 /home/pixie/public_html/app/Mage.php(448): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('sales_model_ser...', Array)
#13 /home/pixie/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Service/Quote.php(191): Mage::dispatchEvent('sales_model_ser...', Array)
#14 /home/pixie/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Service/Quote.php(249): Mage_Sales_Model_Service_Quote->submitOrder()
#15 /home/pixie/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Model/Type/Onepage.php(785): Mage_Sales_Model_Service_Quote->submitAll()
#16 /home/pixie/public_html/app/code/local/Ebizmarts/SagePaySuite/controllers/FormPaymentController.php(181): Mage_Checkout_Model_Type_Onepage->saveOrder()
#17 /home/pixie/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Ebizmarts_SagePaySuite_FormPaymentController->successAction()
#18 /home/pixie/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('success')
#19 /home/pixie/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#20 /home/pixie/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#21 /home/pixie/public_html/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#22 /home/pixie/public_html/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#23 {main}

Next exception 'Zend_Db_Statement_Exception' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '48-0-1' for key 'PRIMARY'' in /home/pixie/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:234
Stack trace:
#0 /home/pixie/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 /home/pixie/public_html/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#2 /home/pixie/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#3 /home/pixie/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `ca...', Array)
#4 /home/pixie/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(428): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `ca...', Array)
#5 /home/pixie/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Indexer/Price/Default.php(564): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('INSERT INTO `ca...')
#6 /home/pixie/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Indexer/Price/Default.php(142): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Indexer_Price_Default->_movePriceDataToIndexTable()
#7 /home/pixie/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Indexer/Price.php(315): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Indexer_Price_Default->reindexEntity(Array)
#8 /home/pixie/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/CatalogInventory/Model/Observer.php(749): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Indexer_Price->reindexProductIds(Array)
#9 /home/pixie/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1338): Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Observer->reindexQuoteInventory(Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#10 /home/pixie/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1317): Mage_Core_Model_App->_callObserverMethod(Object(Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Observer), 'reindexQuoteInv...', Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#11 /home/pixie/public_html/app/Mage.php(448): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('sales_model_ser...', Array)
#12 /home/pixie/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Service/Quote.php(191): Mage::dispatchEvent('sales_model_ser...', Array)
#13 /home/pixie/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Service/Quote.php(249): Mage_Sales_Model_Service_Quote->submitOrder()
#14 /home/pixie/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Model/Type/Onepage.php(785): Mage_Sales_Model_Service_Quote->submitAll()
#15 /home/pixie/public_html/app/code/local/Ebizmarts/SagePaySuite/controllers/FormPaymentController.php(181): Mage_Checkout_Model_Type_Onepage->saveOrder()
#16 /home/pixie/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Ebizmarts_SagePaySuite_FormPaymentController->successAction()
#17 /home/pixie/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('success')
#18 /home/pixie/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#19 /home/pixie/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#20 /home/pixie/public_html/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#21 /home/pixie/public_html/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#22 {main}
```

Comment: Your best bet is to contact Sage or the dev for the module and tell them about it. (dev site is there http://ebizmarts.com/contact-us). As the error clearly states, something, for some reason, prevented a SQL to execute, because the entry 48-0-1 already existed in the Database.

Comment: Thanks, posted it on the forum a couple of days ago with no real response yet so I thought I'd ask on here as well and see if anyone had come across it.

Comment: system.log and/or exception.log in `path/to/magento/var/log` may maybe help you find further bug report, or any file in `path/to/magento/var/report`. Your error line alone is no clue for anyone to help, IMO, considering the fact that it is a custom module and not a core one, which make the amount of people having the exact same configuration as yours really tight, I'm afraid.

Comment: Ross, as replied on our forums here http://ebizmarts.com/forums/topics/view/15114 please identify the SQL query, its related to the Magento CORE indexer routine, not our module please identify the SQL query by for example logging SQL queries and check which Magento table you need to check for health